If all Humanity came from Adam and Eve and the flood happened (Gen 7), how could there be people in different continents when they were discovered?

19 Higher and higher on the earth the waters swelled, until all the
highest mountains under the heavens were submerged. 20 The waters
swelled fifteen cubits higher than the submerged mountains. 21 All
creatures that moved on earth perished: birds, tame animals, wild
animals, and all that teemed on the earth, as well as all
humankind.(E) 22 Everything on dry land with the breath of life in its
nostrils died. 23 The Lord wiped out every being on earth: human
beings and animals, the crawling things and the birds of the air; all
were wiped out from the earth. Only Noah and those with him in the ark
were left. (Genesis 7)

Say why there were people in different continents when they were discovered.

Welcome to the group Tiago. Please take the Tour (bottom left of the page) to get oriented. Normally we require specific biblical verses. Since it's clear what you refer to here I too the liberty of inserting it.

The answer to your question can be summed up in one word . . . . . . . . boats.

I’m voting to close this question because this belongs on another site.

Hi Tiago, unfortunately the text does not really speak to this question, and so any answers you receive will be entirely opinion based.

There are basically two ways to answer this question:
Long Lost Relatives. Noah's family expanded to repopulate the Earth after the waters receded. The beginning of this process is described in Genesis 10-11. As Noah's descendants spread far and wide after the famous confusion of tongues that resulted from the Tower of Babel episode, they lost touch with people in the Middle East and the "civilized" world. Thus, when new continents were "discovered" by Europeans, these people were unknown; but in reality they were Noah's descendants. A. John M. Osgood explains:

The Bible indicates profoundly and unambiguously that all the present
world’s population are descendants of the three sons of Noah (Genesis
10:32): Shem, Ham, and Japheth are the origin of all the families of
the earth. Genesis 10, moreover, gives a detailed family basis for
that origin, listing somewhere around 65 original family groups at the
moment of dispersion (some variation is possible, depending on which
groups one holds to be the significant ones). These family groups all
came from the sons of Noah and spread out over the entire earth after
the dispersion from Babel.

Some populations survived. The second answer is that the Flood was not actually worldwide, but covered mainly the area of Fertile Crescent. This view is explained on the basis of the language and worldview of the biblical writers. The Flood could have covered the entire known world but not necessarily the entire Earth. The account uses two words that are often translated as "earth" in English, making us think that the whole planet was covered. However one of them (eretz) can also mean "land" or "country" and the other ("ha-adama") can mean ground. According to David Instone Brewer:

Old Testament Hebrew has a vocabulary of only 8,000 words – far fewer
than the English language – so words tend to have a wide range of
meanings. In Genesis 6, where the story of the flood is told, the word
eretz could mean ‘planet’ or ‘earth’, but more often means ‘land’ or
‘country’ – such as the “land of Havilah” near Eden in Genesis 2:11.
Similarly, the word for ‘mountain’ (har) is also used for ‘hill’ –
such as the hill that David stood on to address his men in 1 Samuel
26:13. So the text is ambiguous: it says either that the waters
covered all the mountains of the planet or earth, or all the hills of
the land or country.

Conclusion: Either the people who were "discovered" in previously unknown continents were descendants of Noah who had lost touch with their relatives, or the Flood was not actually a worldwide event.

For behold, I will bring a flood of waters upon the earth to destroy all flesh in which is the breath of life under heaven. Genesis 6:17. The context is clear - 'earth', in this verse, means 'everywhere under heaven'.
